# Performance related to Not exists function

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables a and b,each have 2 M and 3.2 Million records. I'am trying to get those id's which are not exists in b from a. I have written below query,

```
select a.id from a where not exists (select b.id from b where a.id =b.id)
```

this is taking longer time. is there any better way to get results faster.

Update: I just look into the table structure for both tables and found table a.id has decimal datatype and table b.id has varchar as datatype

will this difference in datatype cause any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the `LEFT JOIN` with `NULL`. It will return the Id's which are exists in TableA and those are not in TableB.

```
SELECT T1.Id
FROM TableA T1
LEFT JOIN TableB T2 ON T2.Id = T1.Id
WHERE T2.Id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, even this is taking longer time. Even though I have indexes on both the tables

Answer (score 0):

While you *could* write your query using an anti-join, it probably would not affect the performance much, and in fact the underlying execution plan could even be the same.  The only way I can see to speed up your query would be to add an index to the `b` table:

```
CREATE TABLE idx ON b (id);
```

But, if `b.id` be a primary key, then it should already be part of the clustered index.  In this case, your current performance might be as good as you can get.

Comment: Thanks for Reply, table a.id has primary key and on B table i have created index on b.id. still the performance is low

Comment: Well how big are these tables?  For really massive tables, any operation could take some time.

Answer (score 0):

(this is mostly comment, but it's a bit long)

Please take some time to read some of the many questions about query optimization here is SO. The ones which are downvoted and closed omit table/index definitions and explain plans. The ones which will receive upvotes include these along with cardinality, performance and result metrics.

The join to table a in your sub query is redundant. When you remove the second reference to that table you end up with a simpler query. Then you can use a "not in" or a left join.

But the performance is still going to suck. Wherever possible you should try to avoid painting yourself into a corner like this in your data design.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your valuable answers, I found the way. It got resolved after keeping same datatypes for lookup ID's, got results in 22 sec.